# DeprecationWarning: object.__init__() takes no parameters

Tags: python, sympy

I've searched and can't quite get an answer to this. I want a simple subclass of Matrix from sympy with specific dimensions. When I run this code in python 2.7:

```
from sympy import *
class JVec(Matrix):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(JVec,self).__init__(*args)
        #Matrix.__init__(self, *args)
        if self.shape != (2,1):
            raise TypeError("JVec: shape must be (2,1)")
a = JVec([1,0])
```

I get the error

```
/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:4: 
DeprecationWarning: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

I get the same error whether I use the code as is, or replace the `__init__` in the line I commented out.

Comment: I ran your code through **sympy-0.7.6.1** with either `Matrix.__init__(self, *args)` or `super(Matrix, self).__init__(*args)` and did not see that problem. If possible, try to update the **sympy** package to see if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem arises from the fact that calling `super(JVec,self).__init__(*args)` will find the `__init__` defined by `object` since neither of the base classes define an `__init__` method.

`sympy`'s code is using [a different mechanism](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) to create new instances. You should re-write you function to be:

```
class JVec(Matrix):
    def __new__(cls, *args):
        newobj = Matrix.__new__(cls, *args)
        if newobj.shape != (2, 1):
            raise TypeError("JVec: shape must be (2,1)")
        return newobj
```

That's based on the way they are [creating the RayTransferMatrix instances](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/a57f3c43b9c86979ff7fe04d520bc404b94d859a/sympy/physics/optics/gaussopt.py#L111).

Answer (score 0):

I can produce the message as an `error` with:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...    def __init__(self,*args):
...        super(Foo,self).__init__(*args)
... 
>>> Foo()
<__main__.Foo object at 0xb744370c>
>>> Foo('one')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

That's not exactly your problem, but may give ideas of how to dig further.